# Keeping historical record data

Tags: history-tracking

We have a custom object where we like to be able to take a snapshot of the a record at any given time - to be able to look it up later for comparison, as the data in the record gets updated. So historical data, but not editable. Literately i was told i could take a screenshot. What kind of options are there, not sure where to begin! thanks!

Comment: see [VF page to PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm) is what you need. You could also consider [Historical trend reporting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_historical_limits.htm&language=en_US), but it's very limited. Or even try a "geeky" Big Data path by implementing [Salesforce2hadoop](https://github.com/datadudes/salesforce2hadoop)

Comment: Thanks Olek. The data is only displayed in a VF page, so i dont thinks snapshots will do - unles i create another VF page to display the snaphots. I think all i need to do is be able to add a "Create PDF" button on the VF page.